# How can I read an excel file using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, xlsx

I am trying to pandas to open and extract xlsx files.

Here is the function:

```
def read_data(DataFile):
    xlsLoad = pd.ExcelFile(DataFile)
    Bus = pd.read_excel(xlsLoad, 'bus').set_index('id')
    Gen = pd.read_excel(xlsLoad, 'gen').set_index('id')
    Line = pd.read_excel(xlsLoad, 'line').set_index('id')
    #id should be a column with unique information. 
    
    return Bus, Gen, Line


Bus, Gen, Line = read_data('RTS_Data.xlsx')
print("Data was read successfully.")
N=Bus.index
G=Gen.index
K=Line.index
```

I run the following code and it works. Unfortunately I have too much code to change that needs to run pd.ExcelFile()
I have also successfully run pip install openpyxl.

The full traceback error I am getting is this

```
> AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\Users\britt\Desktop\PythonLearn\PythonDCOPF\DCOPF.ipynb Cell 4 in <cell line: 3>()
      1 # Read Data
      2 #print(os.getcwd())
----> 3 Bus, Gen, Line = read_data('RTS_Data.xlsx')
      4 print("Data was read successfully.")
      5 N=Bus.index

c:\Users\britt\Desktop\PythonLearn\PythonDCOPF\DCOPF.ipynb Cell 4 in read_data(DataFile)
      1 def read_data(DataFile):
      2     #xlsLoad = pd.ExcelFile.parse(DataFile)
----> 3     Bus = pd.read_excel(DataFile, 'bus').set_index('id')
      4     Gen = pd.read_excel(DataFile, 'gen').set_index('id')
      5     Line = pd.read_excel(DataFile, 'line').set_index('id')

File c:\Users\britt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py:211, in deprecate_kwarg.<locals>._deprecate_kwarg.<locals>.wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    209     else:
    210         kwargs[new_arg_name] = new_arg_value
--> 211 return func(*args, **kwargs)

File c:\Users\britt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py:331, in deprecate_nonkeyword_arguments.<locals>.decorate.<locals>.wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    325 if len(args) > num_allow_args:
    326     warnings.warn(
    327         msg.format(arguments=_format_argument_list(allow_args)),
...
--> 109     sheet.defined_names[name] = defn
    111 elif reserved == "Print_Titles":
    112     titles = PrintTitles.from_string(defn.value)

AttributeError: 'ReadOnlyWorksheet' object has no attribute 'defined_names'
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and provide the _full traceback_ of the errors. It would be helpful if these tracebacks were posted immediately after the code that produces them. A `FileNotFoundError` suggests that the file you've specified doesn't exist.

Comment: generally `pd.read_excel()` will work fine. note that if you have multiple sheets you would need to specify which one as an argument.  Here are the docs:  https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html

Comment: I used import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\britt\Desktop\PythonLearn\PythonDCOPF\PythonDCOPF\RTS_Data.csv")

print(df.head())    This works.

Answer (score 0):

I provided a link to the docs in the comments, but this might be useful for you.

I just ran this:

```py
import pandas as pd

file = 'G:\\python\\tests\\filename.xlsx'
df = pd.read_excel(file)

print(df)
```

i was prompted to add this dependency:

```
ImportError: Missing optional dependency 'openpyxl'.  Use pip or conda to install openpyxl.
```

So i did `pip install openpyxl`. and ran the same code again and it worked.

My excel had just one tab, so it looked like a csv file.

here are the docs and there are some good worked examples at the bottom:
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html

Answer (score 0):

try

import pandas as pd
import openpyxl

source = pd.excelfile("yourfile.xlsx")

df = pd.read_excel(source, "sheet1", header=[0])

I hope this helps

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).